# Checar se múltiplos elementos HTML contém um valor de texto específico

Tags: javascript, html

**Quero veríficar se os elementos inseridos em inputs já existem em algum campo da tabela onde a classe é chamada "codigo".**

*Criei uma variável para conter todas as classes código para então verificar.*

```
let codigos = document.querySelectorAll(".codigo")
```

*Na parte "//criação de nova tabela" em verificações (ifs) foi inserida a condição que está como*

```
else if (codigos.contains(id)) { window.alert("Id já cadastrado") }
```

Segue o código inteiro do projeto para os testes:

```js
let botaoInserirPessoa = document.querySelector("#inserirPessoa");
let tabela = document.querySelector("#cadastrosPessoa")
let codigos = document.querySelectorAll(".codigo")

let campoId = document.querySelector("#id")
let campoNome = document.querySelector("#nome")
let campoCpf = document.querySelector("#cpf")
let campoRg = document.querySelector("#rg")
let campoNascimento = document.querySelector("#dataNascimento")
let campoSexo = document.querySelector("#sexo")

let bancoDeCadastros = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
    "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
    "rg": "47.360.897-2",
    "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
    "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
    "rg": "40.974.782-8",
    "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
    "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
    "rg": "36.214.141-1",
    "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nome": "Cristiane Renata Ana das Neves",
    "cpf": "946.074.401-08",
    "rg": "32.301.736-8",
    "data_nasc": "10/05/1966",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nome": "Priscila Benedita Vanessa Ferreira",
    "cpf": "888.282.394-68",
    "rg": "44.524.670-4",
    "data_nasc": "15/11/1966",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "nome": "Bianca Carolina Nunes",
    "cpf": "484.323.140-13",
    "rg": "44.466.563-8",
    "data_nasc": "16/03/1948",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "nome": "Yuri Vicente Manuel Silveira",
    "cpf": "250.111.093-56",
    "rg": "18.597.361-9",
    "data_nasc": "05/09/1974",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "nome": "Melissa Alessandra Barros",
    "cpf": "446.675.916-25",
    "rg": "25.598.673-7",
    "data_nasc": "13/01/2000",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "nome": "Márcia Daniela Lara da Cruz",
    "cpf": "932.803.826-02",
    "rg": "40.653.176-6",
    "data_nasc": "04/06/1986",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "nome": "Filipe Anderson Rafael Assis",
    "cpf": "704.869.005-41",
    "rg": "39.383.334-3",
    "data_nasc": "19/11/1995",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "nome": "Luís Vinicius Sebastião Jesus",
    "cpf": "035.960.588-56",
    "rg": "29.915.692-8",
    "data_nasc": "23/04/1965",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "nome": "Cecília Caroline Nascimento",
    "cpf": "034.396.672-78",
    "rg": "48.673.066-9",
    "data_nasc": "04/02/1951",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "nome": "Raimunda Sandra Ferreira",
    "cpf": "757.187.891-85",
    "rg": "21.189.806-5",
    "data_nasc": "17/11/1974",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "nome": "Andreia Isabelly Juliana Melo",
    "cpf": "736.348.985-85",
    "rg": "24.677.018-1",
    "data_nasc": "11/10/1963",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "nome": "Nicolas Bernardo Moura",
    "cpf": "061.370.865-26",
    "rg": "16.302.343-8",
    "data_nasc": "08/06/1989",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "nome": "Diego Benjamin Tiago da Luz",
    "cpf": "991.152.443-42",
    "rg": "38.315.100-4",
    "data_nasc": "04/06/1990",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "nome": "Marlene Emanuelly Yasmin Cavalcanti",
    "cpf": "781.233.625-52",
    "rg": "21.068.742-3",
    "data_nasc": "15/10/1961",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "nome": "Vanessa Isabela da Luz",
    "cpf": "872.138.490-85",
    "rg": "44.289.193-3",
    "data_nasc": "05/09/1982",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "nome": "Camila Flávia Vera Mendes",
    "cpf": "790.524.518-77",
    "rg": "40.847.994-2",
    "data_nasc": "01/07/1952",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "nome": "Luana Lívia Lara Campos",
    "cpf": "532.901.056-01",
    "rg": "14.732.946-2",
    "data_nasc": "19/08/1981",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "nome": "Josefa Nina Galvão",
    "cpf": "379.743.833-80",
    "rg": "13.878.690-2",
    "data_nasc": "27/01/1943",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "nome": "Natália Isabelly Silvana da Paz",
    "cpf": "454.172.867-29",
    "rg": "22.986.096-5",
    "data_nasc": "17/09/1980",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "nome": "Amanda Sebastiana Vieira",
    "cpf": "703.941.038-90",
    "rg": "50.251.196-5",
    "data_nasc": "08/06/1960",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "nome": "Noah Pedro Alves",
    "cpf": "074.733.106-58",
    "rg": "32.110.015-3",
    "data_nasc": "14/08/1992",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "nome": "Giovana Camila da Conceição",
    "cpf": "418.746.840-49",
    "rg": "35.520.215-3",
    "data_nasc": "25/06/1947",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "nome": "Pietro Joaquim Emanuel Gonçalves",
    "cpf": "003.502.230-25",
    "rg": "12.099.068-4",
    "data_nasc": "21/04/1999",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "nome": "Tereza Kamilly Mariana Porto",
    "cpf": "050.946.705-90",
    "rg": "39.830.941-3",
    "data_nasc": "16/06/1959",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "nome": "Caroline Emanuelly Lívia Moreira",
    "cpf": "673.831.546-57",
    "rg": "24.561.727-9",
    "data_nasc": "09/04/1948",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "nome": "Gabriel Ricardo da Paz",
    "cpf": "829.270.172-98",
    "rg": "30.407.114-6",
    "data_nasc": "24/03/1980",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "nome": "Giovanni Igor Augusto Pires",
    "cpf": "584.880.490-72",
    "rg": "33.874.271-2",
    "data_nasc": "24/08/1946",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  }
]

//função que transforma todos dados pessoais na tabela editáveis.
let permitirEdicaoDados = ()=>{
  
  let dadosCadastrados = document.querySelectorAll(".dPessoa")
  
  dadosCadastrados.forEach(dado =>{
    dado.setAttribute("contenteditable", true)
  
  })
}

//função que adiciona o evento excluir ao botão lixeira.
let eventoBotaoExcluir = ()=>{
  
  let botaoExcluir = document.querySelectorAll('.material-icons')
  botaoExcluir.forEach((botao) => {
  
    botao.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let idLinha = botao.getAttribute('data-id')
      
      document.getElementById(`${idLinha}`).remove()
    })
  })
}

//função que inclui os cadastros já existentes na base de dados
let renderizarCadastros = banco =>{
    
  for (let i=0; i<bancoDeCadastros.length; i++){    
      
      let novaTabela = `<tr id="${banco[i].id}">  
                          <td class="codigo">${banco[i].id}</td>
                          <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].nome}</td>
                          <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].cpf}</td>
                          <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].rg}</td>
                          <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].data_nasc}</td>
                          <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].sexo}</td>
                          <td class="material-icons" data-id="${banco[i].id}">delete_forever</td>
                      </tr>`
                      
      tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela
  }
}

let limparCamposFormulario = ()=>{
  campoId.value = ""
  campoNome.value = ""
  campoCpf.value = ""
  campoRg.value = ""
  campoNascimento.value = "" 
  campoSexo.value = ""
}

//criação de uma nova tabela
botaoInserirPessoa.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  
  let id = campoId.value
  let nome = campoNome.value
  let cpf = campoCpf.value
  let rg = campoRg.value
  let nascimento = campoNascimento.value
  let sexo = campoSexo.value

  if(id == "" || nome == "" || cpf == "" || rg == "" || nascimento == "" || sexo == ""){
    
    window.alert("Preencha todos os campos")

  }
  
  else if(tabelaTd.classList.contains(id)){
    
    window.alert("Id já cadastrado")
    
  }

  else{
    
    let novaTabela = `<tr id="${id}">  
                        <td class="codigo">${id}</td>
                        <td class="dPessoa">${nome}</td>
                        <td class="dPessoa">${cpf}</td>
                        <td class="dPessoa">${rg}</td>
                        <td class="dPessoa">${nascimento}</td>
                        <td class="dPessoa">${sexo}</td>
                        <td class="material-icons" data-id="${id}">delete_forever</td>
                      </tr>`          
   
  tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela

  let novoCadastro = {
    id: id,
    nome: nome,
    cpf: cpf,
    rg: rg,
    data_nasc: nascimento,
    sexo: sexo,
  }
  
  bancoDeCadastros.push(novoCadastro)
  
  limparCamposFormulario()
  eventoBotaoExcluir()
  permitirEdicaoDados()
  }

})

renderizarCadastros(bancoDeCadastros)
eventoBotaoExcluir()
permitirEdicaoDados()
```

```css
/*Root*/
*{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

/*Container principal*/
#container{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 15px;
}

/*Campos do formulário*/
#inserirDados div, input, button{
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

#inserirDados input{
    width: 120px;
}

#inserirDados button{
    width: 60px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    
    color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    background-color: rgb(38, 98, 230);

    transition: .3s;
}
#inserirDados button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(42, 89, 190);
    transition: .3s;
}

/*Tabela*/
#cadastrosPessoa{
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}

#cadastrosPessoa tr{
    transition: .2s;
}

#cadastrosPessoa tr:hover{
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    transition: .2s;
}

#cadastrosPessoa th{
    border: 0;
}

#cadastrosPessoa td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid  rgb(51, 233, 111);
    font-weight: normal;

    padding: 5px;
}

#cadastrosPessoa .material-icons{
    cursor:pointer;
    display: contents;
    
    transition: .3s;
}

#cadastrosPessoa .material-icons:hover{
    
    color: tomato;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Listagem de pessoas</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="container">
        <div id="inserirDados">
            <h1>Adicionar colaborador</h1>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="ID">
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
            <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF">
            <input type="text" name="rg" id="rg" placeholder="RG">
            <input type="text" name="dataNascimento" id="dataNascimento" placeholder="Nascimento">
            <input type="text" name="sexo" id="sexo" placeholder="Sexo">
            <br>
            <button id="inserirPessoa">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <table id="cadastrosPessoa">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>RG</th>
            <th>Nascimento</th>
            <th>Sexo</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
        
</body>

<script src="/scripts.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
rel="stylesheet">

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E sempre bom você separar as funcionalidades do seu código e funcões específicas. No seu caso seria bom criar uma funcão que somente verifica se algum `id` já foi cadastrado e na hora de inserir um novo item na tabela, execute a funcão que verifica se o `id` informado já existe.

Vou criar uma funcão chamada `checkIdAlreadyExist(id)` onde ela recebe o **`id` do item que vai ser cadastrado** e verifica se ele já existe. Vou colocar o codigo e as explicacões:

Código:

```
function checkIdAlreadyExist(id) {
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  const idsArray = [];

  trs.forEach((tr) => {
    idsArray.push(tr.getAttribute('id'));
  });

  if (idsArray.includes(id)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Explicacões:

- `const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');` seleciona todos os elementos que sao um `<tr>`
- `const idsArray = [];` array que vamos usar para armazenar os `id`s
- No código abaixo, vamos iterar sobre todos os elementos `tr` e vamos "pegar" o atributo `id` de cada um deles usando `getAttribute` e adicioná-los ao array de `id`s que criamos (`idsArray`):

```
  trs.forEach((tr) => {
   idsArray.push(tr.getAttribute('id'));
  })
```

- `if (idsArray.includes(id)) {...}` aqui fazemos a verificação pra ver se o `id` informado já existe, através do método `includes`, onde ele retorna `true` ou `false`.

Esta é a função e ela serve somente para isto e voce vai chamá-la dentro da função que adiciona um novo item na tabela. Baseado no retorno dela, voce decide o que fazer. No seu caso enviar uma mensagem para o usuário.

Insira esta chamada de funcão dentro do seu `if`, assim:

```
...
else if (checkIdAlreadyExist(id)) {
        window.alert('Id já cadastrado');
      }
....
```

Como fica seu código completo:

```js
    let botaoInserirPessoa = document.querySelector('#inserirPessoa');
    let tabela = document.querySelector('#cadastrosPessoa');
    let codigos = document.querySelectorAll('.codigo');

    let campoId = document.querySelector('#id');
    let campoNome = document.querySelector('#nome');
    let campoCpf = document.querySelector('#cpf');
    let campoRg = document.querySelector('#rg');
    let campoNascimento = document.querySelector('#dataNascimento');
    let campoSexo = document.querySelector('#sexo');

    let bancoDeCadastros = [
      {
        id: 1,
        nome: 'Francisca Julia da Costa',
        cpf: '457.696.936-65',
        rg: '47.360.897-2',
        data_nasc: '23/03/1944',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nome: 'Noah Felipe Silva',
        cpf: '956.531.431-70',
        rg: '40.974.782-8',
        data_nasc: '11/07/1964',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nome: 'Alícia Rosângela Melo',
        cpf: '066.291.353-18',
        rg: '36.214.141-1',
        data_nasc: '18/02/1978',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        nome: 'Cristiane Renata Ana das Neves',
        cpf: '946.074.401-08',
        rg: '32.301.736-8',
        data_nasc: '10/05/1966',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        nome: 'Priscila Benedita Vanessa Ferreira',
        cpf: '888.282.394-68',
        rg: '44.524.670-4',
        data_nasc: '15/11/1966',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        nome: 'Bianca Carolina Nunes',
        cpf: '484.323.140-13',
        rg: '44.466.563-8',
        data_nasc: '16/03/1948',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        nome: 'Yuri Vicente Manuel Silveira',
        cpf: '250.111.093-56',
        rg: '18.597.361-9',
        data_nasc: '05/09/1974',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        nome: 'Melissa Alessandra Barros',
        cpf: '446.675.916-25',
        rg: '25.598.673-7',
        data_nasc: '13/01/2000',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        nome: 'Márcia Daniela Lara da Cruz',
        cpf: '932.803.826-02',
        rg: '40.653.176-6',
        data_nasc: '04/06/1986',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        nome: 'Filipe Anderson Rafael Assis',
        cpf: '704.869.005-41',
        rg: '39.383.334-3',
        data_nasc: '19/11/1995',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        nome: 'Luís Vinicius Sebastião Jesus',
        cpf: '035.960.588-56',
        rg: '29.915.692-8',
        data_nasc: '23/04/1965',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        nome: 'Cecília Caroline Nascimento',
        cpf: '034.396.672-78',
        rg: '48.673.066-9',
        data_nasc: '04/02/1951',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        nome: 'Raimunda Sandra Ferreira',
        cpf: '757.187.891-85',
        rg: '21.189.806-5',
        data_nasc: '17/11/1974',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        nome: 'Andreia Isabelly Juliana Melo',
        cpf: '736.348.985-85',
        rg: '24.677.018-1',
        data_nasc: '11/10/1963',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        nome: 'Nicolas Bernardo Moura',
        cpf: '061.370.865-26',
        rg: '16.302.343-8',
        data_nasc: '08/06/1989',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 16,
        nome: 'Diego Benjamin Tiago da Luz',
        cpf: '991.152.443-42',
        rg: '38.315.100-4',
        data_nasc: '04/06/1990',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 17,
        nome: 'Marlene Emanuelly Yasmin Cavalcanti',
        cpf: '781.233.625-52',
        rg: '21.068.742-3',
        data_nasc: '05/09/1982',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 18,
        nome: 'Vanessa Isabela da Luz',
        cpf: '872.138.490-85',
        rg: '44.289.193-3',
        data_nasc: '05/09/1982',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 19,
        nome: 'Camila Flávia Vera Mendes',
        cpf: '790.524.518-77',
        rg: '40.847.994-2',
        data_nasc: '01/07/1952',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 20,
        nome: 'Luana Lívia Lara Campos',
        cpf: '532.901.056-01',
        rg: '14.732.946-2',
        data_nasc: '19/08/1981',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 21,
        nome: 'Josefa Nina Galvão',
        cpf: '379.743.833-80',
        rg: '13.878.690-2',
        data_nasc: '27/01/1943',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        nome: 'Natália Isabelly Silvana da Paz',
        cpf: '454.172.867-29',
        rg: '22.986.096-5',
        data_nasc: '17/09/1980',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 23,
        nome: 'Amanda Sebastiana Vieira',
        cpf: '703.941.038-90',
        rg: '50.251.196-5',
        data_nasc: '08/06/1960',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 24,
        nome: 'Noah Pedro Alves',
        cpf: '074.733.106-58',
        rg: '32.110.015-3',
        data_nasc: '14/08/1992',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 25,
        nome: 'Giovana Camila da Conceição',
        cpf: '418.746.840-49',
        rg: '35.520.215-3',
        data_nasc: '25/06/1947',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 26,
        nome: 'Pietro Joaquim Emanuel Gonçalves',
        cpf: '003.502.230-25',
        rg: '12.099.068-4',
        data_nasc: '21/04/1999',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 27,
        nome: 'Tereza Kamilly Mariana Porto',
        cpf: '050.946.705-90',
        rg: '39.830.941-3',
        data_nasc: '16/06/1959',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 28,
        nome: 'Caroline Emanuelly Lívia Moreira',
        cpf: '673.831.546-57',
        rg: '24.561.727-9',
        data_nasc: '09/04/1948',
        sexo: 'Feminino',
      },
      {
        id: 29,
        nome: 'Gabriel Ricardo da Paz',
        cpf: '829.270.172-98',
        rg: '30.407.114-6',
        data_nasc: '24/03/1980',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
      {
        id: 30,
        nome: 'Giovanni Igor Augusto Pires',
        cpf: '584.880.490-72',
        rg: '33.874.271-2',
        data_nasc: '24/08/1946',
        sexo: 'Masculino',
      },
    ];

    //função que transforma todos dados pessoais na tabela editáveis.
    let permitirEdicaoDados = () => {
      let dadosCadastrados = document.querySelectorAll('.dPessoa');

      dadosCadastrados.forEach((dado) => {
        dado.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
      });
    };

    //função que adiciona o evento excluir ao botão lixeira.
    let eventoBotaoExcluir = () => {
      let botaoExcluir = document.querySelectorAll('.material-icons');
      botaoExcluir.forEach((botao) => {
        botao.addEventListener('click', () => {
          let idLinha = botao.getAttribute('data-id');

          document.getElementById(`${idLinha}`).remove();
        });
      });
    };

    //função que inclui os cadastros já existentes na base de dados
    let renderizarCadastros = (banco) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < bancoDeCadastros.length; i++) {
        let novaTabela = `<tr id="${banco[i].id}">
                              <td class="codigo">${banco[i].id}</td>
                              <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].nome}</td>
                              <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].cpf}</td>
                              <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].rg}</td>
                              <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].data_nasc}</td>
                              <td class="dPessoa">${banco[i].sexo}</td>
                              <td class="material-icons" data-id="${banco[i].id}">delete_forever</td>
                          </tr>`;

        tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela;
      }
    };

    let limparCamposFormulario = () => {
      campoId.value = '';
      campoNome.value = '';
      campoCpf.value = '';
      campoRg.value = '';
      campoNascimento.value = '';
      campoSexo.value = '';
    };

    function checkIdAlreadyExist(id) {
      const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
      const idsArray = [];

      trs.forEach((tr) => {
        idsArray.push(tr.getAttribute('id'));
      });

      if (idsArray.includes(id)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    //criação de uma nova tabela
    botaoInserirPessoa.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let id = campoId.value;
      let nome = campoNome.value;
      let cpf = campoCpf.value;
      let rg = campoRg.value;
      let nascimento = campoNascimento.value;
      let sexo = campoSexo.value;

      if (
        id == '' ||
        nome == '' ||
        cpf == '' ||
        rg == '' ||
        nascimento == '' ||
        sexo == ''
      ) {
        window.alert('Preencha todos os campos');
      } else if (checkIdAlreadyExist(id)) {
        window.alert('Id já cadastrado');
      } else {
        let novaTabela = `<tr id="${id}">
                            <td class="codigo">${id}</td>
                            <td class="dPessoa">${nome}</td>
                            <td class="dPessoa">${cpf}</td>
                            <td class="dPessoa">${rg}</td>
                            <td class="dPessoa">${nascimento}</td>
                            <td class="dPessoa">${sexo}</td>
                            <td class="material-icons" data-id="${id}">delete_forever</td>
                          </tr>`;

        tabela.innerHTML += novaTabela;

        let novoCadastro = {
          id: id,
          nome: nome,
          cpf: cpf,
          rg: rg,
          data_nasc: nascimento,
          sexo: sexo,
        };

        bancoDeCadastros.push(novoCadastro);

        limparCamposFormulario();
        eventoBotaoExcluir();
        permitirEdicaoDados();
      }
    });

    renderizarCadastros(bancoDeCadastros);
    eventoBotaoExcluir();
    permitirEdicaoDados();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Listagem de pessoas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="inserirDados">
        <h1>Adicionar colaborador</h1>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="ID" />
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF" />
        <input type="text" name="rg" id="rg" placeholder="RG" />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="dataNascimento"
          id="dataNascimento"
          placeholder="Nascimento"
        />
        <input type="text" name="sexo" id="sexo" placeholder="Sexo" />
        <br />
        <button id="inserirPessoa">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table id="cadastrosPessoa">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>CPF</th>
        <th>RG</th>
        <th>Nascimento</th>
        <th>Sexo</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
</html>
```

<sub>Não adicionei o CSS pois não vem ao caso.</sub>

Esta é apenas uma sugestão do que podes fazer, agora só adapte para o seu código usando a variável `codigo`.

Comment: Olá @CmteCardeal, novamente seu código foi de uma enorme ajuda para mim, confesso que esta sua logica criando a função para descobrir a duplicidade da ID está um pouco além da minha capacidade, então vou estudar este seu código. **Agradeço novamente pela ajuda, muito obrigado!!!**

Comment: Nao se preocupe, a medida que voce for estudando e praticando, vai perceber que sua logica vai melhorar e vai conseguir resolver problemas muito  mais facilmente.